# Tor + Dashlane = Anonymous?

Tags: anonymity

**could you tell me whether it is a wise idea to use Tor
in conjunction with the password manager Dashlane?**

While Dashlane can store data locally, it still requires
- as far as I am correct here - a login to their site, each
time you want to unlock your password safe.

I can image this under circumstances compromising your anonymity.

Answer (score 3):

You can completely use Dashlane in conjunction with Tor, there is no reason why it shouldn’t work. Though, in my opinion it does not make a lot of sense considering that a password manager's purpose is to log you into websites with your accounts, and once this is done, you are not anonymous anymore on those websites.

On a side note, login into your Dashlane account does not require any internet connection, the requests which are sent when you login are sent to sync your personal data, and to check whether your device is still authorized (http://support.dashlane.com/customer/portal/articles/656784-what-happens-if-my-phone-is-lost-or-stolen-with-all-my-dashlane-data-).

Disclaimer: I am a developer at Dashlane.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds as if using Dashlane will harm your anonymity however if you click the new identity button after logging in to Dashlane then you will regain your anonymity. Also Firefox has an [inbuilt password save feature](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/security-and-passwords-settings?esab=a&s=password+store&r=6&as=s#w_passwords).